# No me inserta ningun registro en my base de datos Mysqli-Php

Tags: php, mysqli

¿Alguien podría ayudarme de favor a identificar que podría estar mal en mi código?, he seguido la sintaxis para insertar registros con Mysqli pero no he podido resolver mi problema:
Este es mi conexión a la BD:

La tengo dentro de una carpeta(lib)
config.php

```
<?php    

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "prueba");

if($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Falló la conexion a la base de datos";
}

return $mysqli;

?>

Este es mi registro.php

<?php
ob_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">  

    <form action="" method="post">

      <div class="form-group has-feedback">

        <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre completo" required>

        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star form-control-feedback"></span>

      </div>

      <div class="form-group has-feedback">

        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required>  
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="text" name="usuario" class="form-control" placeholder="Usuario" required>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="password" name="contrasena" class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña" required>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
      </div>
     <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="password" name="repcontrasena" class="form-control" placeholder="Repita la contraseña" required>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in form-control-feedback"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-10">
          <div class="checkbox icheck">
            <label>

              <input type="checkbox" name="check" required> Acepto los <a href="#">términos y condiciones</a>
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <button type="submit" name="registrar" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Registrarme</button>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
      </div>
    </form>
<body>

    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['registrar'])) {

    require("lib/config.php");

      $nombre = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['nombre']);
      $email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
      $usuario = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['usuario']);
      $contrasena = md5($_POST['contrasena']);
      $repcontrasena = md5($_POST['repcontrasena']);


      $comprobarusuario = "SELECT usuario FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '$usuario'";
      $comprobaremail = "SELECT email FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$email'";

    if($resultadousuario = $mysqli->query($comprobarusuario));
    $numerousuario = $resultadousuario->num_rows;

    if($resultadoemail = $mysqli->query($comprobaremail));
    $numeroemail = $resultadoemail->num_rows;

    if($numeroemail>0) {
      echo "Este correo ya esta registrado, intenta con otro.";
    }

    elseif($numerousuario>0) {
      echo "Este usuario ya existe.";
    }

    elseif($contrasena != $repcontrasena) {
    echo "Las contraseñas no coinciden.";
    }
    else {

      $query = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre,email,usuario,contrasena,fecha_reg) values ('$nombre','$email','$usuario','$contrasena',now())";

       if($registrar = $mysqli->query($query)) {
        echo "Felicidades $usuario se ha registrado correctamente, te hemos enviado un correo de confirmacion.";
    header("Refresh: 2; URL=login.php");

    }
      else {

        echo "Ha ocurrido un error en el registro, intentelo de nuevo";
        header("Refresh: 2; URL=registro.php");

      }


    }

    $mysqli->close();

    }
    ?>


    <br>
    <a href="login.php" class="text-center">Tengo actualmente una cuenta</a>

    </body>
    </html>
    <?php
    ob_end_flush();
    ?>
```

Y esta es la estructura de mi Bd:

Nombre de mi BD:prueba.

Tabla: usuarios.

```
Campos: id_use int(11) auto_increment primary key.    
nombre varchar(100).    
usuario varchar(100).    
contrasena varchar(100).    
nacimiento date.    
avatar varchar(200).    
email varchar(100).    
sexo varchar(100).    
fecha_reg datetime.    
verificado int(11).    
privada int(11).
```

Comment: Que es lo que pasa cuando intentas agregar un usuario?

Comment: Hola estimado agradezco tu tiempo, pues se salta hasta mi ultimo else: Ha ocurrido un error en el registro, intentelo de nuevo";

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error? ¿qué significa esta línea: `return $mysqli;`?  Además, en PHP no existe `now()` tal cual, debes crearlo a partir de `DateTime`, darle un formato para que te saque el valor como cadena y ponerlo además rodeado de comillas simples en la sentencia. Algo así: 1º Creas una cadena de la fecha actual con formato:  $ahora = (new DateTime('now'))->format('Y-m-d');` 2º. En la consulta: `$query = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre,email,usuario,contrasena,fecha_reg) values ('$nombre','$email','$usuario','$contrasena','$ahora')";` pasas el valor de la variable, rodeándolo de `''`

Comment: Hola estimado, pues estuve investigando y encontre que now() permite obtener la fecha en tiempo real en que el usuario se loguea, ya he utilizado esta funcion en otros formularios y no me ha dado error, aqui ya he intentado cambiar variables e incluso probar tu query pero aun me sigue dando error, y no se ya a que se deba. saludos.

Comment: Pero que error te da?

Comment: Hola estimado, pone: ha ocurrido un error en el registro, intentelo de nuevo. ya revise mis variables las conexiones, las validaciones  y no encuentro el motivo de falla

Comment: Imprime la consulta: `echo $query;` y dinos cómo se está creando. Intenta luego ejecutarla directamente en la base de datos. Yo continúo con mis sospechas sobre `now()`.